# extract information from an image from forms

Tags: python, nlp, ocr, tesseract, named-entity-recognition

I have some form filled with

> name:something, family name: something and etc.

all the pages are similar format.
I have the images of this forms. first I extracted the text from image by `tesseract(python)` then I am trying to convert each page to a dictionary:

```
{ "page1":{"name":"something","family_name":"something",etc}
```

which method is the best? I used the regex and it does not give me good result because for example name may be return as name in tesseract output? what is the best open source solution?
should I change tesseract? is there any machine learning model I can replace with regex? should I use image processing? How can I train a model to learn my form patterns to extract the data.

I tried tesseract and regex but the results are not good because the image does not have a good quality.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want first of all detect fields from the image form and then use ocr model to get text from those fields, in that case I recommend detector [facterrcnn](https://github.com/jwyang/faster-rcnn.pytorch)
faster rccn detector for extracting box where for exampe `name` placed in the form + [easyocr](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR#easyocr) for text recognition from this box. It's pretty good solution for structed image forms

detector finds for you all types of the fields and you can fill dictionaries with returning value from ocr model